# Cannot get memory allocated from `flex_array_alloc` when requesting a relatively big size in linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I'm doing some linux kernel development.

And I'm going to allocate some memory space with something like:

`ptr = flex_array_alloc(size=136B, num=1<<16, GFP_KERNEL)`

And `ptr` turns out to be `NULL` every time I try.

What's more, when I change the size to 20B or num to 256，there's nothing wrong and the memory can be obtained.

So I want to know if there are some limitations for requesting memory in linux kernel modules.  And how to debug it or to allocate a big memory space.

Thanks.

---

And `kzalloc` has a similar behavior in my environment. That is, requesting a `136B * (1<<16)` space failed, while `20B` or `1<<8` succeed.

Comment: With respect to your edit: `kzalloc` is a variant of `kmalloc` which zeros out the allocation. `kmalloc` is "the normal method of allocating memory for **objects smaller than page size** in the kernel." If you want to allocate larger objects, you need to use `vmalloc`/`vzalloc`. For the limitations of flexible arrays, see my (edited) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two limits to the size of an array allocated with `flex_array_allocate`. First, the object size itself must not exceed a single page, as indicated in https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/flexible-arrays.txt:

> The down sides are that the arrays cannot be indexed directly, individual object size cannot exceed the system page size, and putting data into a flexible array requires a copy operation.

Second, there is a maximum number of elements in the array.

Both limitations are the result of the implementation technique:

> …the need for memory from `vmalloc()` can be eliminated by piecing together an array from smaller parts…
>
> A flexible array holds an arbitrary (within limits) number of fixed-sized objects, accessed via an integer index.…  **Only single-page allocations are made**…

The array is "pieced" together by using an array of pointers to individual parts, where each part is one system page. Since this array is also allocated, and only single-page allocations are made (as noted above), the maximum number of parts is slightly less than the number of pointers which can fit in a page (slightly less because there is also some bookkeeping data.) In effect, this limits the total size of a flexible array to about 2MB on systems with 8-byte pointers and 4kb pages. (The precise limitation will vary depending on the amount of wasted space in a page if the object size is not a power of two.)